# ¿Realizar una consulta MATCH AGAINST pero solo primera palabra?

Tags: php, mysql

Buenos días. Estoy trabajando con un script php de un buscador que realiza una consulta a una base de datos *mysql* usando MATCH AGAINST en una columna con FULLTEXT INDEX el problema es por ejemplo, si en mi base de datos tengo "Comida Mexicana" y en el buscador escribo "M" me devuelve "Comida Mexicana" y lo que yo quiero es que me devuelva solo los resultados que tengan esa letra en la primera palabra, la consulta la estoy haciendo así:

```
 $search_query = $_POST['searchQuery'] . '*';
 $sql = "SELECT cat FROM cat_table WHERE MATCH(cat) AGAINST(:search_query  IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es solo tener en cuenta la primera palabra a la hora de realizar el `MATCH`, esto se puede realizar con `SUBSTRING_INDEX`:

```
$search_query = $_POST['searchQuery'] . '*';
$sql = "SELECT cat FROM cat_table WHERE MATCH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cat, " ", 1)) AGAINST(:search_query  IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

Más información en: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index